# How to batch compress sub subfolders?

Tags: windows, batch, compression

I'm on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have a directory that looks like this:

```
Folder01
    Subfolder 1
        File1
        File2
        File3
    Subfolder 2
        File1
        File2
    Subfolder 3
        File1
        File2
        File3
Folder02
    Subfolder 1
        File1
        File2
        File3
    Subfolder 2
        File1
        File2
    Subfolder 3
        File1
        File2
        File3
Folder03
    Subfolder 1
        File1
        File2
        File3
    Subfolder 2
        File1
        File2
    Subfolder 3
        File1
        File2
        File3
```

The final result should look like this:

```
Folder01
   SubFolder 1.zip
   Subfolder 2.zip
   Subfolder 3.zip
Folder02
   SubFolder 1.zip
   Subfolder 2.zip
Folder03
   SubFolder 1.zip
   Subfolder 2.zip
   Subfolder 3.zip
```

As you can see there are multiple parent folders and I want to compress each subfolder in all parent folders. After compressing I want the files in the subfolder deleted. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, Enter to the root folder(Parent folder) and select all the sub-folders which are under the root folder. Now select all the root folders by using Ctrl+A. And then now right click it and select the option "Send to -> Compressed (Zipped) Folder".

Comment: that won't work cause I have multiple parent folders and I want to compress each subfolder in multiple parent folders

Comment: Maybe you should make a diagram of what the result should look like to help us all out.

Comment: @mdpc I've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Try out this Batch Script on a small subset of the actual data or test it with some dummy data.Replace the Paths as needed. You need to have WinRAR installed for this to work.

```
@echo off
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\WinRAR
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,3) DO (
CD Q:\FOLDER%%G
FOR /D /R %%G IN ("*") DO (
ECHO This is %%G
WINRAR a -afzip -df %%G %%G
)
)
pause
```